# Safe way of connecting to database using PHP PDO/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have currently created this code from various tutorials and the PHP Manual (changed personal settings to 123)

```
$username = "123"; 
$password = "123"; 
$host = "localhost"; 
$dbname = "123"; 

try {
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=123', $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected";

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "I'm sorry Charlie, I'm afraid i cant do that.";
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
    $dbh = null;
}
```

I was just wondering if this is the best/safest way to connect to the database? Other examples i have saw people have uses classes and private and public functions? I am new to PDO and my next steps are to insert, update, and delete data. I have built this before using mysql but thought it would be best to have a full understanding of PDO. Any hints, tips or advice would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is safe but the main problems can occurs while inserting unquoted data (although PDO can be used to do it).

I suggest you to use another database layer (ORM) like [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.db.html) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), this will make your life really easier and your development safer since they handle some of the tough work for you.

Comment: I suggest you to not use another database layer. PDO is enough powerful and can quote data (who said `quoteInto()`?).

Comment: Is this similar to CodeIgniter and CakePHP? I was hoping to grow confidence in standard PHP and then moving on to a framework.

Comment: @Balboa Zend is similar to CakePHP and CodeIgniter but you can use Zend_Db without the rest of the Framework. I do suggest you to learn how to use a framework as soon as you get the basic principles of PHP (when you start thinking about security I think you're at the right point). It'll force you to have a better structure in your code and to learn some concept like MVC.

Comment: @Florent PDO can quote data indeed, Zend_Db "just" does it automatically.

Comment: Thank you AsTeR, It's quite hard to tell when i'm ready, I didn't want to jump straight into it and wanted to grasp how to write PHP if for some reason i could not use a framework in the future and was used to using one.